# Visual Studio Code debugger tool error message for C++

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

Working with visual studio code on a mac. I'm running the debugger on my mac but am getting an error message as the following:

```
"Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected LLDB output from command "-exec-run". process exited with status -1 (attach failed ((os/kern) invalid argument))
The program '/Users/user/Documents/C++/1' has exited with code 42 (0x0000002a)."
```

I was thinking the issue might be because of my current configurations:

```json
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "cpp - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
        }
      ]
    }
```

Any help would be wonderful. Thank you.

Comment: Would that be an M1 mac? Debugging on those is not supported yet by VS code - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/7035

Comment: Ya, I just got it. So debugging doesn't work on this computer with visual studio code?

Comment: or i guess just with cpp/c i'm assuming?